# POSIX find all non readable files

Tags: find, posix

I am trying to find all non readable 'ACL-wise' in a subdirectory owned by another user `www-data`, and that on a 'FreeBSD' server. This server prevents me from using the command `find . ! -readable`

How could I find all the non-readable (by the current user) files in a directory?

Comment: Similar: [How to recursively check if a specfic user has read access to a folder and its contents?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/210093)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always do:

```
find . -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    [ -r "$file" ] || printf "%s\n" "$file"
  done' sh {} +
```

To list the files *you* don't have read permission for.

Note that for symlinks, that checks the target of the symlink.

It also obviously won't report files in directories you don't have read permission to (which may contain files you have read access to (provided you have search access to the directory) and/or files you don't have read access to).

On FreeBSD, you should also be able to do:

```
find . -print0 | perl -Mfiletest=access -l -0ne 'print unless -r'
```

Or

```
sudo find . -print0 | perl -Mfiletest=access -l -0ne 'print unless -r'
```

To also list the files in the directories you don't have read access to.

(neither `sudo`, `-print0` nor `perl` are specified by POSIX).